# Android: My 48x48 Launcher Icon looks smaller when compared to others

Tags: android, icons, launcher

I have designed a launcher icon **48x48** pixels and placed it in my res/drawable folder. When I install the application, the icon in the application menu seems to be smaller and it is wrapped in a box by default. Did I do something wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

48x48 should be for a mdpi screen. What device are you displaying it on? Also, is it saved as a transparent PNG or a JPEG?

Comment: I have Samsung galaxy 3 which has WQVGA (240 x 400 pixel) resolution display. I don't know if it is mdpi. And yes it is saved as a transparent PNG

Comment: Yours is actually ldpi, so you should actually be using a 36 x 36 pixel icon, and place it into a drawable/ldpi folder. Granted, that's probably not the cause of your problem. Try adding `<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>` into your manifest, and see what that does.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. That worked for me. Also I desiged a 36 x 36 pixel icon and placed into drawable-ldbi folder, a 48 x 48 pixel icon and placed into drawable-mdpi folder and a 72 x 72 pixel icon into drawable-hdpi folder.